# ionic 3 'ion-item' is not a known element: 1. If 'ion-item' is an Angular component,

Tags: ionic3

'ion-item' is not a known element:

1. If 'ion-item' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-item' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)

it is working properly but getting this error

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhuNe.png)